# Is a property reference to an NSManagedObject unsafe?

Tags: ios, core-data

In the book [Learning Core Data for iOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321905768), the author creates several `UIViewControllers` which each have a property that refers to an `NSManagedObjectID`.

In example,

```
@interface LocationAtShopViewController : UIViewController   
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectID *selectedObjectID;
// ... other properties and methods
@end
```

In this manner, he is able to pass an `NSManagedObjectID` from one controller to another and retrieve the associated `NSManagedObject` object using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `existingObjectWithID:error:` method.

Further, he doesn't ***ever*** set an `NSManagedObject` object directly (even if he already has a variable reference to it), nor does he keep a reference to the `NSManagedObject` object very long (instead, he retrieves it in each method that he needs it).

Is it **unsafe** (i.e. will cause crashes or lead to unexpected behavior in certain circumstances) to pass an `NSManagedObject` directly between controllers via a property reference, or simply keep a reference to it on a controller?

In example,

```
@interface LocationAtShopViewController : UIViewController   
@property (strong, nonatomic) LocationAtShop *locationAtShop;
// ... other properties and methods
@end
```

Assuming a **single**, shared `NSManagedObjectContext` is used, so disregard issues caused by passing between multiple contexts, which isn't safe in general.

Comment: I have setup controllers with properties/ivars pointing directly to NSManagedObject instances and haven't seen any issues yet. I'm very curious why to know why only the ID is stored in that book's examples. Maybe I'm doing something horribly wrong...

Comment: @Alex, I'm doing the same thing and am concerned if it's causing or related to some peculiar crashes I'm seeing (randomly occurring, the worse kind), but I'm not sure... :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reason to avoid using the managed object directly, provided that:

- You only use the managed object with a single managed object context, and
- You either

  - only ever use the managed object on a single thread or queue, or
  - Make sure to use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` when working on a different queue.

Keeping only the object ID may be less error-prone since it makes it a lot harder to accidentally mix up contexts or queues. That may make it a better idea for less experienced developers, who are therefore less likely to screw things up. But it's certainly not wrong nor even especially dangerous to keep the object itself.

Comment: Is this true even if the referenced `NSManagedObject` is deleted from said *single* context and the property isn't explicitly set to nil (i.e. separate controller initiates the delete and save on the context without updating the referenced property to nil)?

Comment: Per http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW7, I believe the described situation would lead to `Fault cannot be fulfilled`. Technically, this isn't a direct result of keeping a property reference to said `NSManagedObject`. However, it can be a potential consequence of it, so I find that "it can possibly be unsafe", given deletion of the object.

Answer (score 6):

### Is it safe ?

Yes, it's safe, with some caveats:

Per [Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43832/tom-harrington)'s answer, *in general* it's safe to store an `NSManagedObject` as a property on a controller.

However, there are situations in which this can cause problems. Notably,

**If the referenced NSManagedObject is deleted and its context is saved, the property must explicitly be set to nil.**

If you do ***not*** explicitly set the property to `nil`, the next time you try to access an attribute on the object, it will cause a `CoreData could not fulfill a fault` crash.

### Why did the author of *Learning Core Data for iOS* pass and store the NSManagedObjectID instead of the NSManagedObject?

The likely reasons may include:

If instead of storing the `NSManagedObject` as a property you stored the `NSManagedObjectID`, you don't have to worry too much about the object being deleted.

This is because `NSManagedObjectContext`'s method `existingObjectWithID:error:` will return `nil` in the event that `the object cannot be fetched, or does not exist, or cannot be faulted`.

So, it's ***safer*** to store the `NSManagedObjectID` as a property than it is to store the `NSManagedObject`, if deletion of the object is possible.